# Unable to align rows of text when one row has less text in it

Tags: html, email, html-table, html-email

I am writing HTML for an email, one section of the email currently looks like this. The problem is that the last row has a strange alignment. Oddly, the only solution I have found appears to be to add more text in the last row. But I don't like this solution.

[image: Example of output]

Here is the exact code used to create the output above in Chrome.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateContainer" style="border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;background-color: #FFFFFF;" width="600">

<tr style="color: rgb(97, 97, 97); display: block; font-family: 'Proxima Nova'; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 21px;">
<td style="padding-left: 18%; padding-right: 20%; padding-top: 35px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
<center>
<table style="border:0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr>
  <td align="left" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-family: sans-serif;">
      <span style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova', sans-serif !important; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 300;">
  <span style="color: rgb(107, 107, 207); font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400;">imperdiet</span>
    – Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed porta, lacus dictum ornare elementum, magna eros cursus lectus, sed ullamcorper mi diam vehicula augue.
  </span> 
  </td>
</tr>  
</table>
</center>
</td>
</tr>

<tr style="color: rgb(97, 97, 97); display: block; font-family: 'Proxima Nova'; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 21px;">
<td style="padding-left: 18%; padding-right: 20%; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
<center>
<table style="border:0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr>
  <td align="left" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-family: sans-serif;">
    <span style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova', sans-serif !important; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 300;">
      <span style="color: rgb(107, 107, 207); font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400;">Phasellus</span>
        – Vestibulum cursus elit vel urna lacinia feugiat. Maecenas vel varius eros. Maecenas vel mattis sem. Proin ac mauris quis elit suscipit tristique eu eu risus
    </span>  
  </td> 
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</td>
</tr>


<tr style="color: rgb(97, 97, 97); display: block; font-family: 'Proxima Nova'; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 21px;">
<td style="padding-left: 18%; padding-right: 20%; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
<center>
<table style="border:0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr>
  <td align="left" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-family: sans-serif;">
    <span style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova', sans-serif !important; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 300;">
      <span style="color: rgb(107, 107, 207); font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400;">dictum</span>
        – Ut commodo tincidunt dictum. In hendrerit
      </span>
  </td>
</tr>   
</table>
</center>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Note that this is not normal HTML but HTML used specifically for email (hence the ugliness)

Comment: Not an answer, but you can strip out the `<center>` and second level table elements, just leaving the `span` inside the `<td>` and it has no impact on the output.

Comment: You might be right, but really a lot of these weird tags are due to outlook's email rendering. I would need to confirm these changes work in outlook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a set width for your table cells. That will fix your issue!

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateContainer" style="border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;background-color: #FFFFFF;" width="600">

<tr style="color: rgb(97, 97, 97); display: block; font-family: 'Proxima Nova'; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 21px;">
<td style="padding-left: 18%; padding-right: 20%; padding-top: 35px; padding-bottom: 0px; width: 800px">
<center>
<table style="border:0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr>
  <td align="left" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-family: sans-serif; width: 800px">
      <span style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova', sans-serif !important; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 300;">
  <span style="color: rgb(107, 107, 207); font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400;">imperdiet</span>
    – Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed porta, lacus dictum ornare elementum, magna eros cursus lectus, sed ullamcorper mi diam vehicula augue.
  </span> 
  </td>
</tr>  
</table>
</center>
</td>
</tr>

<tr style="color: rgb(97, 97, 97); display: block; font-family: 'Proxima Nova'; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 21px;">
<td style="padding-left: 18%; padding-right: 20%; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; width: 800px">
<center>
<table style="border:0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr>
  <td align="left" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-family: sans-serif; width: 800px">
    <span style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova', sans-serif !important; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 300;">
      <span style="color: rgb(107, 107, 207); font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400;">Phasellus</span>
        – Vestibulum cursus elit vel urna lacinia feugiat. Maecenas vel varius eros. Maecenas vel mattis sem. Proin ac mauris quis elit suscipit tristique eu eu risus
    </span>  
  </td> 
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</td>
</tr>


<tr style="color: rgb(97, 97, 97); display: block; font-family: 'Proxima Nova'; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 21px;">
<td style="padding-left: 18%; padding-right: 20%; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; width: 800px">
<center>
<table style="border:0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr>
  <td align="left" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-family: sans-serif; width: 800px">
    <span style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova', sans-serif !important; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 300;">
      <span style="color: rgb(107, 107, 207); font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400;">dictum</span>
        – Ut commodo tincidunt dictum. In hendrerit
      </span>
  </td>
</tr>   
</table>
</center>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the first level `<td>` elements to `display: block;` it fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix this would simply be to insert "padding-left: 18%" into your table row "tr" tag.  Since changing the padding was not working for the data "td" tag, the next thing to try would be moving what is seen as the entire row.  So, the revised code for the dictum section would be as listed below.

```html
<tr style="padding-left: 18%; color: rgb(97, 97, 97); display: block; font-family: 'Proxima Nova'; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 21px;">
<td style=" padding-right: 18%; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
<center>
<table style="border:0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr>
  <td align="left" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-family: sans-serif;">
    <span style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova', sans-serif !important; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 300;">
      <span style="color: rgb(107, 107, 207); font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400;">dictum</span>
        – Ut commodo tincidunt dictum. In hendrerit.
    </span>  
  </td> 
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</td>
</tr>


</table>
```